# Can not use subtract operator with Double.MAX_VALUE Java

Tags: java, double, precision

I'm trying the following code:

```
Double a = Double.MAX_VALUE - (1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000);
System.out.println(a);
```

However, the result is still `1.7976931348623157E308` (max value of Double)

Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: What is `1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000` ?

Comment: why will you do that?

Comment: Possibly because 1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000 is too small compared to Double.MAX_VALUE

Comment: 1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000 is too small, but I dont understand the way Double type will process after subtracting it, maybe rounding error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000` is the multiplication of 3 integers, which results in an overflow.

Even if you avoid the overflow by writing :

```
Double a = Double.MAX_VALUE - (1000000000.0 * 100000000.0 * 1000000.0);
```

you are still likely to see no difference since the number you are subtracting from `Double.MAX_VALUE` is negligible compared to `Double.MAX_VALUE` (~1.797*10^308, which is about 275 orders of magnitude larger than what you are trying to subtract from it).

Answer (score 1):

Double.MAX_VALUE is so huge (note the "E308", it means the written number has 308 digits) that whatever you subtract from it (despite Double.MAX_VALUE or near value) will be lost due to rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have an overflow

```
(1000000000 * 100000000 * 1000000);
```

this part overflow so the number is much smaller, you should convert it to double, like

```
(1000000000.0 * 100000000.0 * 1000000.0);
```

and also, double has a limited accuracy, so doing small operations on big number may not yield the right result.